# Silex and autloading controller classes

Tags: php, composer-php, silex, psr-4

I am having problems getting class autoloading to work in the Silex skeleton I am putting together.  I have this working in another project, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.
My directory looks like this:

```
root
 -src
    -Controller
       -HelloController.php
    -app.php
 -vendor
 -web
   -index.php
 -composer.json
```

Here is my index.php

```
<?php
$app = require __DIR__.'/../src/app.php';
$app->run();
```

app.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;
$app->get("/hello/{name}", 'App\Controller\HelloController::hello');
return $app;
```

HelloController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class HelloController
{
    public function hello($name)
    {
        return new Response('<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello, '.$name.'</h1></body></html>');
    }
}
```

and composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "^1.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "/src"
      }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to open index.php/hello/world in a browser, I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in ControllerResolver.php line 153: 
Class "App\Controller\HelloController" does not exist
```

Comment: You need to register `ServiceControllerServiceProvider` that is shipping with this package, which would automatically extends the existing `resolver` service and you should be able to load your controller.

Comment: @Artamiel Isn't necessary. `HelloController` is not a service. http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#controllers-as-classes

Comment: @absalon.valdes - absolutely right. It appears to be not so obvious mistake may be. I tested the provided code and it's working as expected.

Comment: My code worked for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `psr-4` is not working. Add a dot before `'/src'`

```
"App\\": "./src"
```

or move the slash to the end

```
"App\\": "src/"
```

or just remove the slash. The path must be relative.

Comment: That didn't change anything.  Also, I have another project that I made for work that had a very similar directory structure, where the controllers are in a controller folder inside of an src folder in the same directory as the composer.json and it's autoload section looks like this: `"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {"NCBP\\": "src/"}
  },` and that seems to work fine

Comment: Please run `composer dumpautoload --optimize` and check that `HelloController` is correctly mapped in `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`

Comment: Also, `"NCBP\\": "src/"` is not the same as the `composer.json` from your question.

Comment: You're right, it is different, i seriously just now caught that my other project has the slash after the src rather than before.  I'll play with it some more to see if that fixes it

Comment: Tweaked my composer.json and ran composer update, worked perfect, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

in composer.json change

```
"App\\": "/src"
```

to

```
"App\\": "src"
```

You can find 
***SilexSkeleton with controllers as php classes***
example on GitHub: https://github.com/jaresz/SilexSkeleton